# Exception occurring when trying to open a file with python

Tags: python, path

I am trying to open a file with python like this:

```
m = open("e.txt", 'r')
```

The text file I'm trying to open is in the same directory as my python file is.
However I'm getting an error message.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'e.txt'
```

I've also tried using:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd() # cwd: current working directory
path = os.path.join(cwd, "e.txt")
```

The error message looks a little different this time:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\e.txt'
```

I hope someone can help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello @gamer_294 , I think you need to change it like tihs `m = open("e.txt", 'r')`

Comment: The file needs to be in the directory **from where you call the script**, not the directory where the script exists.

Comment: @IceBear yes I'm sorry it is like that I will edit my question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your issue. Either you have the file present, in which case you won't get an exception, or the file is not present in which case you *will* get the exception. Either way, in general, you need to handle both cases.

Comment: @gamer_294 , may I ask if you really do have a `"e.txt"` on your directory? cause if not  I think you need to have it when you run your program cause with the second param `'r'` says `read`. Thanks!

Comment: @Djib2011 Thank you, that helped. But please avoid answering questions in comments and write an answer instead.

Comment: @IceBear I am 100% sure the file exists.

Comment: @gamer_294 I like your comment :)

Comment: @gamer_294 I'm glad it helped, I wasn't sure if that would answer your question or you might have another issue, so I refrained from making an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The could be in a folder, if this is the case then the full name has to be written. Such as:

```
m = open("E://folder/e.txt","r")
print(m.read())
```

It is important to write the EXACT directory of the file.

Comment: I used a relative pathname and after the failed attempt I tried using the absolute one with `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly correct. Check the type of file whether it is .txt or some other file. If everything is correct you should check the location you gave

Comment: As I said I am 100% sure the location I gave is accurate.

Comment: Then u have to check the type (file extension) of file and where your python script is...